# how to fetch profile picture from facebook

Tags: ios, swift, user-profile, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to fetch the profile picture of the user. But as Facebook has update its API sdk to v4.0 or later, and also on the FB developers site, they are explaining in Objective C, but I want code in Swift. I am not getting how to use `FBSDKProfilePicture` in my code. I need help to get profile picture of user.

I want to store the picture in my second view. Please anyone help me to code.
Here is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        println("user already logged in")
        loginManager.logOut()
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
    }

    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
    loginView.center = self.view.center
    loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginView.delegate = self
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onProfileUpdated:", name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

}

func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            println("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
    }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are able to log in with Facebook, then you should have the `FB ID` of that user. With that in hand, you can use this for get the profile picture:

```
func getProfPic(fid: String) -> UIImage? {
    if (fid != "") {
        var imgURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fid! + "/picture?type=large" //type=normal
        var imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString)
        var imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
        var image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can also change the `type` parameter to a different size in the `URL`.

Comment: i would suggest to use `picture?width=10000` in the url, since it will return much more greater size than `type=large`.

Comment: Depends what @Pankaj Kumar wants I guess

Comment: What parameter I should pass to this function while calling ?? Is it the User Id or Name ? @ BHendricks

Comment: The facebook ID of the user you have just logged in

Comment: adding this function, fetches the image. But this function is called after the prepareforsegue method, so am getting a nil value there. Can you say how to solve this ? @ Hendricks

Comment: Please ask another question if you are stuck on something else. I'm glad this correctly got the image though!

Answer (score 1):

to get image of custom size: add parameters of width and height with size you need.

like http://graph.facebook.com/[your_fbid]/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=500&height=500

```
func getProfPic(fid: String) -> UIImage? {
    if (fid != "") {
        var imgURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fid! + "/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=500&height=500" //replace 500 with your desired size
        var imgURL = NSURL(string: imgURLString)
        var imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL!)
        var image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        return image
    }
    return nil
}
```